# Meteor/Cordova: no route for http://meteor.local/

Tags: cordova, meteor

Build Command: meteor build ~/Desktop/Build1 --server http://example.com:80

When I run my Meteor Cordova app (production) I get a router error saying:

Command I ran:

Oops there is no route on the client or server for http://meteor.local/.

Comment: Please do not spam Stackoverflow by posting the same question multiple times.

Comment: I really need an answer.

Comment: Then it's probably best to improve the quality of the question and include, e.g., everything needed to reproduce the problem. Reposting will, if anything, annoy the very people from whom you are seeking an answer.